# Type conversion for std::strings

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is it possible to have something like a global type conversion operator functions for a class? I am specifically looking for a way to expose the `const char*` from the `std::string`. I tried defining a global operator but that doesn't compile. With a quick search and looking at the cpp reference these user defined conversion needs to be member http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator.

Is there any kind of clean (or hacks) way of passing the `std::string` to methods that accepts `const char*` without always using the `c_str()`.

#### Background:

I am working on a cross platform and I am primarily from windows. Most of my classes uses the `ATL::CString`. And I am changing them to use `std::string`'s. Invoking `c_str` is fine, but in the unit test code there seem to be too much of this call every line and every args, so trying to be lazy here.

Comment: Can we see the code "_that doesn't compile_"?

Comment: is it really that hard to call `.c_str()`?  Also why not change the functions to take a `std::string`?

Comment: You're right, that cast operator needs to be a member. You can always derive your own class from `std::string` just to add that cast, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: To add to @NathanOliver, `.c_str()` will be much clearer to others that will read the code, indicating that a C-style string pointer is being used.

Comment: @NathanOliver sometimes you're working with an API that can't be changed, especially one that's C compatible. Microsoft's `CString` class has the auto cast built in for use with its API, and it's quite handy.

Comment: Can't you just write a wrapper with `std::string` parameter that calls the desired function with `c_str()`?

Comment: Have you tried driving a new class from `std::string` and creating a cast operator for that?

Comment: The C++ committee decided **not** to provide an implicit conversion to `const char*` because it's too easy to screw up when you use it. That's why the conversion has that ugly name `c_str()`.

Comment: you can do something like 
`class StringEx : public std::string
{
public:
 operator const char*() { return c_str(); }
};` and use `StringEx` instead of `std::string`.

Comment: I feel inheriting from std string just for this an overkill and introduces a new string type in the code that increases maintenance.

Answer (score 5):

Just as only user-defined types can define their own constructors, only user-defined types can define whether they are implicitly convertible to other types (or from other types via non-`explicit` constructors). So no, you cannot *force* an implicit conversion from `std::string` to `const char*` from outside the class.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Not sure why the standard doesnt still support it as there is a function that does the same.

Comment: @user3279954: You mean why `std::string` doesn't have an implicit conversion operator? It's because you *shouldn't* implicitly convert from a `string` to a `const char*`. It becomes too easy to do it by accident, and since `std::string` owns the memory, you could find yourself holding a destroyed pointer.

Comment: @NicolBolas that's a legitimate concern, but I must say that over many years of using Microsoft's `CString` I've never found it to be a problem in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a function that interfaces the code.

```
some_func(const char* c)
```

to

```
interface(string s) {
    some_func(s.c_str());
}
```

if you make interface's name same as the some_func, it will be better.